# Genre (or category) of White Collar Series according to the image given?

Tags: white-collar

During my period of watching White Collar series, in one of the episodes, I noticed this :

[image]

Now, the red circled area in the image is displaying that the mobile is using 7G internet speed which does not exist at all till now.

The question is **According to this image what can be the genre(or category) of the White Collar series?** Can it be said as `SCI-FI` series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[White collar series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1358522/) falls under the genres' comedy, crime and drama.

There is no 7G internet available till date. The highest generation to known till date is 5G. It is estimated that 5G will be available by 2020.

[See list of mobile phone generations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_generations).

**How is it showing 7G in the image?**

7G does not indicate the mobile communication generation here. It is a voice and network provider used for nation wide and international business purposes in California.

This is the what the [website](http://www.7gnetwork.net/) of 7G Network says:

> 7G Network is a leading provider of voice services and broadband internet. 7G connects top rated businesses and industry leading carriers to the world. If your business needs it, look to 7G Network to provide it.
>
> 7G Network is the best carrier for your nationwide and international business communications. Don't just take our word for it, ask some of your business associates then sign up today.

The person who is holding the phone might be Peter Burke. He is a special agent working for FBI. (Because Dianna Berrigan is the one of the few people Peter trusts.)

For more details see [about](http://www.7gnetwork.net/about) page of respective website.

There is also another chance. It is just exaggerating things in the show. So do not take this thing seriously. Many TV shows show fake things.

Comment: well that answer helped.

Comment: I googled it but  found nothing meaningful so I put a question here.

Comment: No,  the AB&Z network clearly works on 7g mobile standard. And by that i mean the phone is a quick mock up by the art department just like every idiotic hacking moment in the show.

Comment: @cde So, there is a 7G mobile network really in White collar?

Comment: Only if AB&Z is a real cellular company in the show.

Comment: do you mean `6G will be available by 2020.` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `Next Generation Mobile Networks Alliance feel that 5G should be rolled out by 2020 to meet business and consumer demands` It means 5G will be available by 2020. It is just a plan.